# Angular Reactive Form - How to validate radio buttons and show error message when form is submitted

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Goal:
Make the radio buttons required.

Issue:
The element mat-error and its contents are displaying right off the bat, without the form submitted. The element mat-error and its content should only display when the user attempts to submit the form.

I tried adding the on-touch criteria but I could not get it to work!

Any advice is welcome!

HTML:

```
<div class="mat-radio-group">
  <label class="label-mat-radio-group margin-space">Channel visibility</label>
  <mat-radio-group formControlName="visibility" aria-label="Select an option">
    <mat-radio-button value="public">Public</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="private">Private</mat-radio-button>
    <!-- fix: touched is not working -->
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('visibility').invalid">Please select channel visibility.</mat-error>
  </mat-radio-group>

</div>
```

Component:

```
initializeFormAndItsFields() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl(null, {
      validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]
    }),
    visibility: new FormControl(null,{
      validators:[Validators.required]
    }),
    leadType: new FormControl(null,{
      validators:[Validators.required]
    }),
    keywords: new FormControl(null, {
      validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]
    }),
   
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mat-error is showed by defect if the "formControl" is invalid and touched. So, generally you can use markAsTouched when submit

```
  submit(form: FormGroup) {
    if (form.valid) {
      ..do something...
    } else form.markAllAsTouched();
  }
```

A little example in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqady6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-error-example.ts)

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare a flag (`isSubmitted`) to record whether the form is submitted.

```
isSubmitted: boolean = false;
```

2. Add `submit` event to update `isSubmitted` to `true` when the submit button is clicked.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="isSubmitted = true">
  ...
</form>
```

3. Show the error message when `isSubmitted` is `true` and `FormControl` fails the validation.

```
<mat-error *ngIf="isSubmitted && form.get('visibility').invalid">
  Please select channel visibility.
</mat-error>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3yaz8k?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: You can get the same is simply markAsTouched the FormControl (And it's unnecesary use a variable "isSubmitted"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this helps. try `touched` like this

```
<mat-error *ngIf="form.get('visibility').invalid && form.get('visibility').touched">
    Please select channel visibility.
</mat-error>
```

Comment: A mat-error is showed by defect if the "formControl" is invalid and touched, so it's unnecesary add this conditions to the "*ngIf". The only to use *ngIf in a mat-error is when you have more than one Validator in the formControl